# Implementar animación al terminar otra animación con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, libreria

quiero mostrar elementos en mi página web al momento de hacer scroll, pero lo que me interesa es que forzosamente tiene que terminar un efecto para poder comenzar con el otro ya sea con Javascript o con alguna otra librería.
Por ejemplo si el primer elemento se muestra en el segundo 0 al segundo 1, el segundo elemento se debe de mostrar después del segundo 1(por ejemplo del segundo 1 al segundo 2) y asi sucesivamente.

Lo intenté con la libreria AOS(Animate On Scroll Library) pero ni siquiera termina un efecto cuando ya comienza con el otro.

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta guia te puede ayudar, si indicas algo de código, podremos entender mejor el ejemplo:

https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/